# How to access users who did not confirmed and those who confirmed (Rails/Devise/cancan/rolify)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I am building a daily deal app on Rails to train myself to Ruby on Rails.

I have installed authentication with devise/cancan/rolify.

I'd like to create in cancan two type of users

- users who confirmed
- users who did not confirmed yet

How can I achieve that ? how can I access on devise users who have and those who have not confirmed their account(i.e clicked on the activation link sent to them by email).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to add roles for `confirmed` and `unconfirmed`. You can use `user.confirmed?` in your `ability.rb` file to control authorization:

```
# models/ability.rb

if user.confirmed?
  can :manage, Model
end

if !user.confirmed?
  can :view, Model
end
```

Note: you can use an `if/else` construct, but I prefer to keep my rules nicely separated.

In regards to your comments, you're reimplementing what's already been done. With cancan you can use `load_and_authorize_resource` (see: [here](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions)).

```
class ProductsController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

That's it. The user will receive an "unauthorized" response if they try to access without the required permissions.

I highly recommend you read through the documentation for [rolify](https://github.com/EppO/rolify) and [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan).

Comment: thanks but the thing is for certain actions and page i'd like to use sth like a before filter to say "ok this action/page can only be viewed by the confirmed user  and if the user accessing it is only a not_confirmed user, then show him this messages ...i thought that sayign to cancan (setting up a rule) like the users not confirmed will be called by Role="not_confirmed-users" and confirmed users by Role = "confirmed_users" would allow me to manage this more easily but maybe you're right, i do not need to create a new name (like i have for other roles: like User, Superadmin, Manager...

Comment: That's right, keep *role types* separate from *user states*. You can create whatever rules you like, and authorize quite easily within the controller. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: that's be great. thanks a lot (sorry for questions of newbie)

Comment: Updated question with an example, but that's pulled straight from the docs. I'd suggest you read through the documentation for at least rolify and cancan, then devise. For defining abilities, see here: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities